# How to show to whom email was originally destined in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I have a system which receives and send mails to the various members in a group.

Lets say I have a group `support@xyz.com` which have members

1. `member_1@xyz.com`
2. `member_2@xyz.com`

and so on..

Same way there is another group `help@xyz.com` which have members

1. `member_1@xyz.com`
2. `member_3@xyz.com`

and so on..

When I get any mail for `support@xyz.com` it is forwarded to it's member and same way for `help@xyz.com`.

```
mail :from => the_person_who_sent_mail,
     :to => members_email_id,
     :subject => mail_subject,
     :reply_to => the_group_name@xyz.com
```

And it appears like mail was sent to me.

### But I want to do a change in this as shown below :

When it lands in my inbox it should be something like

```
From     :  the_person_who_sent_mail@something.com
Reply To :  the_group_name@xyz.com
To       :   the_group_name@xyz.com
```

But according to my setting it comes like

```
From     :  the_person_who_sent_mail@something.com
Reply To :  the_group_name@xyz.com
To       :   members_email_id@xyz.com
```

In my case it shows that the mail is destined to me. But in the first case it shows to whom the mail was originally destined for.

Comment: So you want to keep the To: header the same, but adjust the rcpt to?  Not sure how you would go about doing this actually since the reading ActionMailer::Base source, it looks like it pulls the To out of the Mail::Message, so getting to To and RCPT to to different values might be challenging.

Comment: @Doon yupp exactly. Banging head from past 2 3 hours and finally had put up question over here !!

Answer (score 1):

Mailing list servers accomplish this with BCC, like so:

```
mail :from => the_person_who_sent_mail,
     :to => the_group_name@xyz.com,
     :subject => mail_subject,
     :reply_to => the_group_name@xyz.com,
     :bcc => [members_email_id]
```

The downside to this is that your mailserver will actually attempt to send the e-mail to the_group_name@xyz.com, so it will have to know to ignore this message. However, when the message arrives in the user's inbox, the To: will be the_group_name@xyz.com.